# How to retrieve current value from ajax JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I used this code:
https://www.webslesson.info/2017/05/json-dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-and-ajax.html

In the JSON file it has the following fields:

```
[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"USA",
        "parent_id":"0"
    }, 
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"Canada",
        "parent_id":"0"
    }, 
    {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"Australia",
        "parent_id":"0"
    }
]
```

but I added another field called "link"

I tried to figure out how to retrieve the current selected "link" but can't figure out how to do so.

I can't figure out where in the code I should add something like cat_link = value.link; in order to get the current link based on the selection made.

For example:

My data file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"USA",
        "link":"www.google.com",
        "parent_id":"0"
    }, 
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"Canada",
        "link":"www.cnn.com",
        "parent_id":"0"
    }, 
    {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"Australia",
        "link":"www.gmail.com",
        "parent_id":"0"
    }
]
```

I want to get the value.link of the combobox selection. Currently this code gets the current id by the following code:

```
 $(document).on('change', '#country', function(){
  var country_id = $(this).val();
  if(country_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('state', country_id);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#state').html('<option value="">Select state</option>');
   $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
  }
 });
```

`var country_id = $(this).val();` gets the current country id but how do I get the current link?

Here is the `load_json_data()`:

```
load_json_data('country');

 function load_json_data(id, parent_id)
 {
  var html_code = '';
  $.getJSON('country_state_city.json', function(data){

   html_code += '<option value="">Select '+id+'</option>';
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if(id == 'country')
    {
     if(value.parent_id == '0')
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if(value.parent_id == parent_id)
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
    }
    }
   });
   $('#'+id).html(html_code);
  });
 }
```

Comment: Please provice a [mcve]

Comment: Missing the code for `load_json_data()` to show how options are created

Comment: It's in that link I posted. I can place it on here as well...

Comment: How is var country_id = $(this).val(); getting the id variable? Shouldn't something like var country_id = $(this).val('link'); work? It gives me [object object] as output...

Comment: Another "developer" that copy-pastes jQuery code into his scripts. Is this really the future for JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do so using the value of the option tag.

Comment: Who would have thunk it